# Error: Server did not accept user credentials

Tags: pop3

```
 Pop3Client pop3Client;
 if (Session["Pop3Client"] == null)
 {
     pop3Client = new Pop3Client();

     pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
            pop3Client.Authenticate("myusername","mypwd",AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
            Session["Pop3Client"] = pop3Client;
 }
```

> Error : Server did not accept user credentials

Comment: You should be describing a bit more what you do, what should be happening and what you have tried to solve this problem. This will more likely will leed to an answer. It is not useful to paste in the error message as title and source code and the error message again as "question"...

Comment: unable to read Gmail Emails using OpenPop.net dll

Comment: You are not supposed to hit me with another error message, but edit personality into your question and explain what your problem is, what you have tried etc.